# Alternative to 'at first' in a more formal way

Tags: synonyms

I am trying to convey the following:

> At first, I aim to perform x.

The 'at first' term should denote that the action that follows will be the first one executed.

I am looking for an alternative, more formal phrasing. I was suggested to use 'first and foremost', but that expression does not relate to time, but importance. In my opinion, 'At first' relates to 90% time order and 10% importance order. I was thinking of 'in first order' or 'in first instance' but these are just calques from my native language.

Comment: Related: http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/890

Comment: "As a first step, ..." or "First to all, ...".  If you mean *in anticipation, in advance or ahead of time*, use "Beforehand".

Comment: What's wrong with being succinct? "First, I will do X."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to sound more formal, **"first and foremost"** seems to fit.

> from [**TFD**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/first+and+foremost) -  "first to be dealt with and most important."

- "First and foremost, I think you should work harder on your biology."
- "First and foremost, I want to thank our sponsors."
- "What we need, first and foremost, is a new secretary."

Answer (score 3):

**Initially**:

> In the early stages, at or **in the beginning**: *Initially, they were wary of him*.
>   [Collins Thesaurus – Complete and Unabridged, 2nd Ed.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/initially)

Answer (score 0):

Initially or as a priority would both work.

The latter denoting more urgency.

Comment: Short answers like this often come up in LQ queue flagged for length and content. In fact, it did.